# Magento front end only printing "local.xml"

Tags: frontend

I went to do a test customer registration and right after I submitted form, the page only loads what you see below. I deleted cookies and loaded the main page, and it has what you see below as well. My coworker was messing with permissions as well, but we think we have all the permissions correct now. There are no errors in magento logs. The only error on server that may be applicable "client denied by server configuration: /var/www/Staging/public_html/app/etc/local.xml" but I know this is a common error and it's been there. Any ideas about what the issue is?

[image]

Comment: are you sure you didn't forget an `echo local.xml` or somewhere similar in the code?

Comment: Just a note: if the "client denied by server configuration" error is _not_ showing up in the logs, it typically means there is a problem. Magento purposely attempts to load the file from the web server over http. If it can't get it, the server puts the error in the log. If it can get it, it means it's not secured properly, and I believe Magento will hiccup when it sees this to prevent the site from running with an unsecured local.xml file to prevent the encryption key and database credentials from being exposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of an XML syntax error, usually in a layout XML file. Based on the update in your cross-post, there is an unclosed root tag.

The following command will tell you which file, though I think you already have your answer.

```
find ./app/design/frontend -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;
```